# Tracking react useEffect dependency array

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a `useEffect` that fetches users from the database and I want to change the view on the frontend without having to reload the page, like when, deleting the user, filtering, searching, etc. I am using `react-redux` in this project and tracking state has never been easy.
My current `useEffect` looks like this.

```js
// render users with each search query and filters
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUsers = () => {
      fetchAllUsers();
    };

    fetchUsers();
  }, [fetchAllUsers, userId, role, searchValue, sortByNameState, sortByJoinDate]);
```

I'll briefly walk you through the dependency array. The `userId` tracks the user delete request, the `role` tracks filtering the user based on the roles, `searchValue` as the name suggests tracks the search result and updates the user's list and so on and so forth.
However, as the app is starting to grow, tracking each request can be cumbersome and I was thinking of having a separate state like `hasChanged` state that I can track instead.
So my `useEffect` now should look something like this.

```js
// render users with each search query and filters
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUsers = () => {
      fetchAllUsers();
    };

    fetchUsers();
  }, [fetchAllUsers, hasChanged]);
```

It would be great if someone enlightens me on the pros and cons, and is the second approach better than the first?

Comment: What does "tracking each request can be cumbersome" mean? The dependency array uses shallow equality checks, and react does that work.

Comment: @DrewReese Ok. I thought that instead of having 5 or 6 states listed, maybe one would suffice.

Comment: Sure, you could create a piece of state that is toggled true when any of those other values update and use that in the effect's dependency array. You may need to then also toggle it back to false in the effect so you don't infinitely loop. Doing this creates more moving pieces in your code though, so there's a trade-off.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Yes, I think the second approach may seem shorter, but in order to avoid infinite loops, I need to toggle back after each request.